# TemplateUrl in Rails not linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't for the life of me get templateUrl from a custom directive to link to html template file in my Rails app.  I've tried using the [angular-rails-templates gem](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) as well as some other methods.  Here's what I have so far:

angular application:

```
window.App = angular.module('myTestApp', ['templates']);

App.directive('testingDiv', [function(){
    console.log('hey')
    return {
        templateUrl: {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'test.html'
        }
    }
}]);
```

(I see the console logged message, so I know I'm getting in there)

test_page.html.slim

```
testing-div
```

app/assets/templates/test.html

```
<div>TESTING!!!!</div>
```

The order I require relevant assets in my application.js file:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree ./angular
```

UPDATE:

I tried just

```
return {
  template: '<div>TEST</div>'
}
```

and it didn't show up either.  Think it has something to do with the slim file?

Comment: Try `/assets/test.html`?

Comment: Are you still using the `angular-rails-templates` gem? Because I am not seeing you require the templates as they state in the README: `//= require_tree ../templates`

Comment: @KurtFunai that doesn't work, and neither does /app/assets/test.html, app/assets/templates/test.html, or /assests/templates/test.html.  Also as per my comment to Alex C, adding the require didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//= require_tree ../templates` or it won't work. I just checked in our code.

Edit: I think there is a mistake in your syntax, fixed version below:

```
App.directive('testingDiv', [function(){
    console.log('hey')
    return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       templateUrl: 'test.html'
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I didn't have that but adding it after require angular-rails-templates doesn't fix it.  I also had the templates folder within ./angular at one time and tried both the short name and the fullpath and neither worked.

Comment: @StevenHarlow just one question, why you put `templateUrl: { restrict: ...` ??

Comment: I just did that so to normalize the way the others reference these directives in the html code.  Restrict AE allows attribute and element tags to be used, but not class references.

Comment: @StevenHarlow my point is that you use templateUrl twice. I don't think this syntax is correct. See my edited answer.

Comment: yes you are correct.  Thanks!  For some reason I had tried that before and it wasn't working, but I think I changed two things around at once...